# Is this use of "that" instead of "when" okay?

Tags: grammar

> Can you suggest a time **that** we can meet and discuss the problem?

Is there anything wrong with this sentence? I thought it should be **when**, not **that**.

Comment: The mistake is in posting a proofreading question. There's nothing wrong with the cited text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers a time, that are correct?

Comment: I can't think of a better way of saying it. What makes you think it might *not* be okay? Note that you should have asked: *"a time", **is that** correct?*

Comment: oic - You could also ask *Can you suggest a time **when** we can meet and discuss the problem?* That's fine too. Offhand I don't know which is more common overall, but I think I'd usually use ***that*** myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you explain how it is correct sentence?

Comment: I'll have to write an answer (it's too long for a comment). But you should *edit your question* to make it clear *exactly what bothers you* (and more particularly, ***why***). I'll be annoyed if it gets closed as proofreading while I'm composing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't immediately see anything unusual in OP's cited text. Until I realised that in fact, the sequence *a time **that*** is relatively uncommon compared to *a time **when***.

It's not easy to find the evidence for my position here, but I think the modern trend is to simplify [relativizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer) usage by either...

> 1) omit the relativizer completely. OP's example would also be fine as...
>    *Can you suggest a time we can meet and discuss the problem?*
>
> 2) use ***that*** instead of "temporal-context-specific" ***when***

Note that #2 above also happens with ***who*** (context-specific for *people*) I think that since *John is the man **that** I saw* is more "generic, simpler" than *John is the man **who** I saw*, it's gaining ground.

Ditto ***where*** (context-specific relativizer for *location*), where *Is there a place **that** we can talk?* or plain *Is there a place we can talk?* are more generic than *...place **where** we can talk.*

---

For what it's worth, Google Books claims 6 hits for [(Can) you suggest a date **that** (is convenient)?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you%20suggest%20a%20date%20that%22), but only 2 for [...you suggest a date **when**...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you%20suggest%20a%20date%20when%22) A small sample size, but it suits my position.